# React Native - Axios- Expo Image picker - upload image to server not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using expo-image-picker for UI interface to upload images to my app. I am finding some diffuculties when I want to upload the images to backend. The images are not uploaded and I don't get the reason. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

1. How I set the data to the image state

   ```
      const showImagePicker = async () => {
        Promise.all([ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync(), ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()]).then(result => {
          result.forEach(permission => {
            return !permission.granted;
          });
        });

        const result: ImagePicker.ImageInfo = (await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          base64: true,
        })) as ImagePicker.ImageInfo;

        const uriParts = result.uri.split('.');
        const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

        if (!result.cancelled) {
          setPickedImagePath({
            uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? result.uri : result.uri.replace('file://', ''),
            name: `photo.${fileType}`,
            type: `application/${fileType}`,
          });
        }
      };
    };
   ```

   2. How I append the data to formData

      ```
      const createRequestCall = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', pickedImage.uri);
        formData.append('data2', 'test');
        formData.append('data3', '123');
        formData.append('data4', 'test');

        dispatch(uploadPhoto(formData));
      };
      ```
   3. How I dispatch the request if file is loading.

```
export const uploadPhoto=
      (photoRequest: FormData) =>
      async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>): Promise<void> => {
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.API_LOADING, payload: apiIsLoading });
        const response = await Apis.requestPhoto(fileRequest);
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.API_LOADING, payload: apiIsNotLoading });
      };
```

4. The request I send to the backend.

```
async requestPhoto(data: FormData): Promise<IDetails> {
    const response = await http.post<IDetails, AxiosResponse<ITripDetailsResponse>>(${baseURL}/upload/image, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      transformRequest(formData, headers) {
        return data;
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using **fetch** instead of **axios** on my api call

Answer (score 0):

I think, that is impossible to send image using `axios` because of the platform.

But, the good news is that `Expo` already has [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/https://) package.
Using it you can upload your image to backend.

Example:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
const imageUploading = async () => {
    const data = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(
      URL,
      image, // uri of the image 
      {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
        fieldName: 'file',
      },
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the other fileds? Can I send formData using FileSystem? In youR solution you have only inclunded image, whereas I need the whole formData to be send to backenD

Comment: `expo-file-system` provides access to a file system stored locally on the device.
So using it you can only send files on user's device.

Comment: Also if you found the answer helpful, please upvote it and/or mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the whole image object works fine:

```
const createRequestCall = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', pickedImage);
  ...

  dispatch(uploadPhoto(formData));
};
```

I use this type:

```
interface ImageType {
  uri: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
}
```

Appending that object works fine even though Typescript gives an error.
`FormData.append` expects a `string | Blob`, but I have yet to figure out how to supply my custom Image type without errors.